# Which versions of Android support native action and share sheets?

Tags: android, native

I'm making improvements to an application and I'd like to use the [native Android bottom sheet](https://material.io/components/sheets-bottom), allowing users to select an option as well as the [native Android sharesheet](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send) for sharing content.

I have a small userbase that is on Android 9 and an even smaller userbase that is on Android 8. I'd like to measure the impact on these users, though can not find any documentation of which Android versions support these native UI elements.

Images for reference: [Bottom sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMoF7.png) + [Share sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbiUI.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to use the native Android bottom sheet

That is not "native", insofar as it is not part of the Android SDK. You can get a bottom sheet from [the Material Components for Android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android), which is the official implementation of some of the advanced UI elements from the site that you linked to. It works back to API Level 14 (Android 4.0).

> as well as the native Android sharesheet for sharing content

[`ACTION_SEND` works back to Android 1.0](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_SEND). What the visual presentation will be is up to the device manufacturer; you and I do not get a vote.